# Business Day Counts btw 2 date series (for countries which have a "friday - saturday" weekend )

Tags: dataframe, numpy, time-series, dayofweek

`I try to calculate the working day counts between 2 date columns for each row.  My data is consisted of different countries all over the world. -I found the working day counts for European countries by:`

df['count'] = np.busday_count (df['Start_Date_column'].tolist(), df['Final_Date_column'].tolist())

`-However, some muslim countries like Oman, Bahrain, Kuwait, Qatar etc. have Friday-Saturday weekend.  Do you have a suggestion for me to solve this problem for these exceptional countries?`

Answer (score 0):

After all, I have solved my problem combining some methods and wanted to share it with everybody who may need it.
I'm kinda beginner in Python, therefore my code could be way improved but here is
the solution which works for me:

P.S: I used some European holidays for trying out, you can customize it in line with your need.

```
start_date= df['start_date']
end_date= df["final_date"]

data = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(start_date,end_date)), columns = ['Start Date', 'End Date'])

dubai_workdays= "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu"
dubai_hol = CustomBusinessDay(holidays= [pd.datetime(2022, 10, 3),
            pd.datetime(2023, 1, 6),
            pd.datetime(2022, 12, 26),
            pd.datetime(2022, 12, 31),
            pd.datetime(2022, 12, 25)],
            weekmask=dubai_workdays)
#pd.bdate_range(pd.datetime(2023, 1, 1), pd.datetime(2023, 1, 2), holidays=dubai_hol, freq= 'C', weekmask = None)
data['Bus_Days'] = data.apply(lambda x: len(pd.bdate_range(x['Start Date'],
                                                           x['End Date'],
                                                           freq= dubai_hol)), axis=1)
```